# How to refactor Spring Integration XML to annotation support?

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-integration

I'm trying to refactor existing xml of `Spring Integration` to the new `4.0.0.` annotations.

```
<!-- the service activator is bound to the tcp input gateways error channel -->
<ip:tcp-inbound-gateway error-channel="errorChannel" />
<int:service-activator input-channel="errorChannel" ref="myService" />
```

But how can I bind the service activator to the error channel as it was in xml?

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public TcpInboundGateway gate() {
        TcpInboundGateway gateway = new TcpInboundGateway();

        //??? how can I bind the service activator class as it was in xml?
        gateway.setErrorChannel(MessageChannel);
        return gateway;
    }
}


@Service
public class MyService {

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "errorChannel")
    public String send(String data) {
        //business logic
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, since I am an author of those new Java and Annotation config features I can help you.

But you should be ready that it isn't so easy to do. To get rid of xml at all you might go with our another new stuff - [Java DSL](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-extensions/tree/master/spring-integration-java-dsl).

I geass we will have several steps to make it worked.

`gateway.setErrorChannel(MessageChannel);` and `@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "errorChannel")`. You must declare `errorChannel` as a bean:

```
@Bean
public MessageChannel errorChannel() {
   return new DirectChannel();
}
```

And use it from that TCP Gateway:

```
gateway.setErrorChannel(this.errorChannel());
```

Or, if you rely on the default `errorChannel` from Framework, you should `@Autowired` it to that `Config`.

Next step. I don't see `@ComponentScan`. That means that your `@ServiceActivator` might not be visible for Application context.

You should provide more options for `TcpInboundGateway` anyway: `connectionFactory`, `requestChannel`, `replyChannel` etc. Everything must be Spring beans.

For a start it is enough. Hope it is clear and makes sense at all for you.

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot. Of course I have `@ComponentScan` in my code. The missing piece was that I can just inject the default error channel as a all other beans, like: `@Qualifier("errorChannel") MessageChannel errorChannel`. It now runs fine again without xml config.